# C# - Login invalid when execute query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am new in C# and learning the query open and close, right now I execute the right query but not getting the correct output. kindly advise me on how to solve this problem thank you.

Here is my query code.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from users Where username = @username and password = @password", sqlcon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

sqlcon.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlcon.Close();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
    Main objMain = new Main();
    this.Hide();
    objMain.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Check your username and password");
}
```

I am getting this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Comment: @marc_s good day, sir I am new in learning c#. Sorry for my line of code that is not correct, can you please share your idea and edit my code? thank you it will be great, but ill try what you have said :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `.ExecuteReader()` **after** `sqlcon.Open()` - and why do you also execute `.ExecuteNonQuery()` ?? You're **already** executing the query by calling `.ExecuteReader()` - this is useless and should be removed (`ExecuteNonQuery` is for SQL statements that run an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` - but **NOT** for cases when you have a `SELECT` like here...).

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @password", sqlcon);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtPassword.Text;

// open connection    
sqlcon.Open();

// execute reader and iterate over rows
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
    Main objMain = new Main();
    this.Hide();
    objMain.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Check your username and password");
}   

// close connection only **AFTER** you've read the data!
sqlcon.Close();
```

Furthermore: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it! Use the regular `Parameters.Add()` method and define the datatype of the parameter!

Additionally: this looks like you're storing your passwords in **plain text** in your database table. ***DON'T DO THIS!*** Seriously - never ever do this. If you must store passwords, then need to be **hashed and salted** - you'll find many many articles and blogs posts on how to do this - **embrace that!**.

And a last note: since you only want to check that a given user exists with a user name and password, it's really an overkill to return **all columns** of the `Users` table - it would be more than enough to just return e.g. the `UserId` (or some other, small column) - and then use `.ExecuteScalar()`. If the user with that username and password exists, his `UserId` is returned by `ExecuteScalar()` - if that user doesn't exist, you'll get back NULL.

Something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @password", sqlcon);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtPassword.Text;

// open connection    
sqlcon.Open();

// execute scalar 
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

// if we got a result --> user with that username nad password exists
if (result != null)
{
    Main objMain = new Main();
    this.Hide();
    objMain.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Check your username and password");
}   

sqlcon.Close();
```

Comment: sir, thank you very much, a flourishing remarks from you and, also to your advice. I'll keep in mind that `ExecuteNonQuery ` is for insert update delete only, it is very great for beginners like me on learning c# and its sql mechanics. I think i only misplaced my line of codes.